# Внешняя команда из массива

Tags: perl

Нубовский вопрос: сейчас не имею доступа к перлу, поэтому вопрос: предположим у меня есть массив

```
@arr = ( 'a' .. 'z' );
```

Если я создам переменную `$ls` и присвою туда индексы букв `ls`:

```
$ls = `@arr[11]@arr[18]`;
```

Так будет работоспособно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

да, будет. Только лучше писать так

```
$ls = `$arr[11]$arr[18]`;
```